# Returning object of type specified in enumeration

Tags: java, generics

I have an enumeration from which I am able to get either a String or a Class

```
public enum EditorialPageDataType {
    BASIC_MODEL_INFORMATION("basic", BasicModelInformation.class),
    GRADES("grades", Grades.class),
    EXTERIOR_COLOURS("extColours", ExteriorColours.class);

    private final String label;
    private final Class<?> typeClass;

    EditorialPageDataType(String label, Class<?> typeClass) {
        this.label = label;
        this.typeClass = typeClass;
    }

    public Class<?> getTypeClass() {
        return typeClass;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
}
```

I want to create something like the following:

```
public T extract(EditorialPageDataType editorialPageDataType) {
    return anotherClass.get(editorialPageDataType.getTypeClass());
}
```

I know I can do the following

```
public <T> T extract(EditorialPageDataType editorialPageDataType, Class<T> classType) {
    return anotherClass.get(classType);
}
```

Where anotherClass is:

```
class anotherClass {
    public <T> T get(Class<T> classToReturn) {
        T objectOfTypeT = getObjectOfType(classToReturn);
        return objectOfTypeT;
    }
}
```

But I wanted to be able to pass in only one parameter if possible and have the type specified by the enumeration.

Comment: What is `anotherClass`, and what is `get()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the generic parameter through with the call:

```
public T extract(EditorialPageDataType editorialPageDataType) {
    return anotherClass.<T>get(editorialPageDataType.getTypeClass());
}
```